# Resolving MVC path

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a problem resolving the path which works for both localhost and the server.
I have placed my project in a `folder in root`.

I have tried

```
   HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/somedata.xml");
```

but it gives me path like `c:\dir1\root\myproject\`

I tried `Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)` which only gives the `host name`

I can check whether it is localhost or not and then hard code the path by adding project name.

But I want to know a way without any hard code.

Any Idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't actually specified what value you expect to get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my project, I used `URL.Content`

```
@Url.Content("~/App_Data/somedata.xml")
```

It works whether I run my app in localhost or deployed it on remote server.